# Como posso enviar um e-mail pelo GMail?

Tags: c#, .net, gmail, smtp, envio-de-email

Quero criar uma aplicação para enviar e-mail e gostaria de usar uma conta do GMail para enviar estes e-mails. Como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Para enviar e-mails você precisa incluir

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;
```

Crie um objeto `MailMessage` e preencha as propriedades:

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();

mail.From = new MailAddress("de@gmail.com");
mail.To.Add("para@gmail.com"); // para
mail.Subject = "Teste"; // assunto
mail.Body = "Testando mensagem de e-mail"; // mensagem

// em caso de anexos
mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(@"C:\teste.txt"));
```

Tendo o objeto mail configurado, o próximo passo é criar um cliente Smtp e enviar o e-mail.

```
using (var smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com"))
{
    smtp.EnableSsl = true; // GMail requer SSL
    smtp.Port = 587;       // porta para SSL
    smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network; // modo de envio
    smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false; // vamos utilizar credencias especificas

    // seu usuário e senha para autenticação
    smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("suaconta@gmail.com", "sua senha");

    // envia o e-mail
    smtp.Send(mail);
}
```

Também é possível enviar e-mails de forma assíncrona, para isso você não pode utilizar o `using`, pois o smtp só pode chamar `Dispose` depois de enviar mensagem. Para isto há o evento `SendCompleted`.

```
smtp.SendCompleted += (s, e) =>
{
    // após o envio pode chamar o Dispose
    smtp.Dispose();
};

// envia assíncronamente
smtp.SendAsync(mail, null);
```

Comment: Vale lembrar que no caso do Gmail é possível que mesmo com o login e senha corretos ele dê falha de autorização, é só gerar uma para o aplicativo específico.Vá em **Segurança > Senhas do app**

Comment: Don, mas isso não é via de regra.

Comment: Quem tiver verificação em duas etapas configurado, é necessário gerar uma `Senha do Aplicativo` e usar no lugar do `password` do e-mail. https://security.google.com/settings/security/apppasswords

Comment: Este procedimento é somente para o Gmail ? queria utilizar o Outlook exchange

Comment: @FabioSouza aí você faz uma pergunta específica para ele. Essa é sobre Gmail.

Answer (score 7):

Uma versão simplificada para enviar emails pelo GMail:

```
using (SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
    {
        Credentials = new NetworkCredential("meumail@gmail.com", "password"),
        EnableSsl = true
    })
{
    client.Send("meumail@gmail.com", "seumail@gmail.com", "test", "test");
}
```

Note que caso a conta de GMail tenha [verificação em duas etapadas](https://www.google.com/intl/pt-BR/landing/2step/) activada, deve gerar uma [password especifica para ser usada com a sua aplicação](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=pt-BR) (e não baixar/comprometer a segurança da sua conta).

Para fazer isso, acesse as a secção da sua conta que permite gerar passwords especificas para aplicações (https://myaccount.google.com/apppasswords), gere uma nova password e use-a quando constrói o cliente.

Answer (score 5):

Todas as soluções mais antigas não funcionam mais. O Gmail não permite mais o uso de sua infraestrutura sem autenticação OAuth2 e o .NET nativamente não permite este tipo de autenticação.

A Microsoft recomenda o uso da biblioteca externa chamada [MailKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit). Ela é mais moderna, robusta, com mais *features*, é mantida atualizada, e atende as demandas atuais, inclusive a [autenticação segura de aplicativos com OAuth2](http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/T_MailKit_Security_SaslMechanismOAuth2.htm).

Você terá que gerar um *token* no Gmail para usar no seu código para autenticar antes de fazer o envio da(s) mensagen(s).

Answer (score 4):

Obs: Está configuração é para o gmail, mas também funciona para outros e-mails, para isto, terá que seguir o procedimento do início ao fim.

Primeiro, crie a clase `GmailEmailService.cs`. Por padrão ela virá da seguinte maneira (pode ser que para você apareça diferente):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace MeuProjeto.LocalClasse
{
    public class GmailEmailService
    {

    }
}
```

Apague o conteúdo gerado dentro das chaves do `namespace`, deixando-o assim:

```
namespace MeuProjeto.LocalClasse
{

}
```

Dentro das chaves do `namespace` cole o seguinte código:

```
public interface IEmailService
{
    bool SendEmailMessage(EmailMessage message);
}
public class SmtpConfiguration
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Host { get; set; }
    public int Port { get; set; }
    public bool Ssl { get; set; }
}
public class EmailMessage
{
    public string ToEmail { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public bool IsHtml { get; set; }
}
public class GmailEmailService : IEmailService
{
    private readonly SmtpConfiguration _config;
    public GmailEmailService()
    {
        _config = new SmtpConfiguration();
        var gmailUserName = "seue-mail@gmail.com";
        var gmailPassword = "suasenha";
        var gmailHost = "smtp.gmail.com";
        var gmailPort = 587;
        var gmailSsl = true;
        _config.Username = gmailUserName;
        _config.Password = gmailPassword;
        _config.Host = gmailHost;
        _config.Port = gmailPort;
        _config.Ssl = gmailSsl;
    }
    public bool SendEmailMessage(EmailMessage message)
    {
        var success = false;
        try
        {
            var smtp = new SmtpClient
            {
                Host = _config.Host,
                Port = _config.Port,
                EnableSsl = _config.Ssl,
                DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
                UseDefaultCredentials = false,
                Credentials = new NetworkCredential(_config.Username, _config.Password)
            };
            using (var smtpMessage = new MailMessage(_config.Username, message.ToEmail))
            {
                smtpMessage.Subject = message.Subject;
                smtpMessage.Body = message.Body;
                smtpMessage.IsBodyHtml = message.IsHtml;
                smtp.Send(smtpMessage);
            }
            success = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //todo: add logging integration
            //throw;
        }
        return success;
    }
}
```

**Acima** do `namespace` importe `using System.Net.Mail;` e `using System.Net;`

Configure seu e-mail e senha no campo (aproximadamente linha 35):

```
 var gmailUserName = "seue-mail@gmail.com";
 var gmailPassword = "suasenha";
```

***ATENÇÃO*** PARA QUE FUNCIONE CORRETAMENTE VOCÊ PRECISA FAZER ESTES PROCEDIMENTOS:

**1º** ACESSAR O GMAIL, ENTRAR EM SUA CONTA

**2º** A SENHA DO GMAIL DEVE SER FORTE, SE NÃO PODE BLOQUEAR O ENVIO

**3º** O LOGIN NÃO PODE SER FEITO EM 2 ETAPAS

**4º** PRECISA DAR PERMISSÃO AO GMAIL PARA QUE FUNCIONE EM APLICATIVOS MENOS SEGURO (IMAGEM ABAIXO), PARA ISSO ACESSE ESTE [LINK](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps) E CLIQUE EM ATIVAR.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**OBS:** ESTE SERVIÇO FUNCIONA COM O GMAIL, PORÉM, O GMAIL POSSIBILITA O USO DE OUTRAS PLATAFORMAS DE E-MAIL PARA ENVIO ATRAVÉS DO GMAIL, ENTÃO SE SEU E-MAIL É DIFERENTE, SIGA ESTAS ETAPAS:

**1º** APÓS TODA ESSA CONFIGURAÇÃO, ACESSE ESTE [LINK](https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#settings/accounts), OU NA SUA CONTA, VÁ EM `CONFIGURAÇÕES` > `CONTAS E IMPORTAÇÕES` E ENTÃO VOCÊ VERÁ O SEGUINTE:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

CLIQUE EM `ADICIONAR OUTRO ENDEREÇO DE E-MAIL` NA JANELA QUE ABRIRÁ, ADICIONE SEU NOME, E O EMAIL DESEJADO, E PREENCHA AS INFORMAÇÕES A SEGUIR DE ACORDO COM O SEU PROVEDOR:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

SE VOCÊ TIVER SUCESSO, APARECERÁ SEU E-MAIL CADASTRADO ABAIXO DO SEU E-MAIL DO GMAIL.

AGORA UTILIZE ESTE CÓDIGO, QUANDO FOR NECESSÁRIO ENVIAR ALGUM E-MAIL (`no controller`):

```
    GmailEmailService gmail = new GmailEmailService();
    EmailMessage msg = new EmailMessage();
    msg.Body = mensagem;
    msg.IsHtml = true;
    msg.Subject = "Cadastro Realizado";
    msg.ToEmail = "destinatario@email.com";
    gmail.SendEmailMessage(msg);
```

Será necessário importar `GmailEmailService`

**Dica:**

O atributo `msg.IsHtml` permite que você envie mensagens com atributos html, ex: `<br/>`, `<b></b>`... etc.

PRONTO, PODE FAZER O TESTE QUE ESTARÁ FUNCIONANDO.

Comment: Sobre aplicativos menos seguros, só depende muito de como a pessoa usa a conta. Concordo que é longe do ideal, mas se é uma conta do google basicamente para email, não tem problema sério nisso. Se a pessoa usa a mesma conta para outros usos, aí ela está revelando a senha para a aplicação, e expondo todo o resto além dos emails. Acho que é mais o caso de um aviso na resposta explicando o que está em jogo.

Comment: @Bacco A questão e que existe o mecanismo de senhas de aplicacão justamente para este caso. Como o cliente SMTP não suporta OAuth, gerar uma senha de aplicacão permite ao utilizador revogar a senha sem ter de mudar a senha da conta .

Comment: @Omni sim, é conforme o que eu disse no comentário acima. Se a conta é para email, bastaria mudar a senha, ou seja, não tem problema nenhum o modo de "aplicativos menos seguros" se for um cenário bem especifico. Se a conta é pra outras coisas, aí está abrindo portas para mau uso da conta. Na verdade talvez tenha faltado eu mencionar que temos 3 cenários: usuário e senha, OAuth2 numa etapa só, ou se forem duas, a sua solução de senhas por aplicação, que são muito práticas por se parecerem com o método usuário e senha.