# Enviar email para servidores diferentes

Tags: c#, web-service, email

Quero que meu programa, feito em C# usando um web service, envie um email todo os dias com um anexo para alguns endereços de email de diferentes servidores. Estava vendo um tutorial e fiquei com uma dúvida. O cara configurou o servidor do hotmail (smtp.live.com:587) pois o email seria enviado e recebido do hotmail. Como eu posso configurar isso para que meu programa possa enviar o email para vários endereços de email diferentes em vários servidores diferentes como, hotmail, gmail, servidor interno de empresa. O servidor configurado serve para a conta remetente e destinatário ou só remetente? Se for o caso de ser só da conta do remetente só preciso configurar o seu servidor?

Segue um print do video tutorial para melhor entendimento:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Desde já agradecida.

Comment: Vamos lá, se entendi direito sua dúvida, você quer saber como enviar vários e-mails para vários endereços de e-mail diferentes. É isso? **Não entendi o motivo para negativar a pergunta, pois ela está bem escrita** _@kaamis ao invés de compartilhar uma imagem, compartilhe o códido, fica melhor de entender_.

Comment: Isso mesmo @PedroCamaraJunior Eu não fiz nada ainda relacionado ao envio do email, por enquanto só estou procurando alguns tutoriais pois nunca tinha feito o envio de email via C#.

Comment: Dica: Poste o código ao invés de um screenshot dele. Todo mundo odeia ter que redigitar código para poder testar ou fazer alterações.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> O servidor configurado serve para a conta remetente e destinatário ou
>   só remetente?

Você irá configurar apenas o remetente, e com esse remetente poderá enviar e-mail para qualquer outro servidor e quantas vezes precisar.

Veja [essa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/630/como-posso-enviar-um-e-mail-pelo-gmail) aqui no SOpt que explica como enviar utilizando o gmail, você pode utilizar qualquer servidor de e-mail para realizar o envio.

Comment: Pedro desculpe discordar da sua resposta, mas se já existe algo que responde aqui no site então marque a pergunta como duplicata ao invés de responder. Tenho certeza que vai entender isto como uma critica construtiva.

Comment: Não julguei como duplicada pois ela não pede "como fazer", a dúvida dela no meu ponto de vista é se precisa configurar vários servidores para envio, um para cada domínio. O que respondi no início da resposta, a segunda parte é apenas um complemento.

Comment: Eu não juguei isto pela pergunta e sim pela sua resposta, se uma outra resposta explica o *como fazer* e a sua resposta aqui soa mais como um comentário, então o melhor caminho é apenas duplicar. Espero que entenda o que quero dizer :)

Comment: Acho que entendi o que tu quis dizer agora. Nesse caso, deveria apenas comentar na própria pergunta , pois se trata de um comentário. Valeu pela dica. ;)

Comment: Isso mesmo Pedro, outra dica, sempre use `@[nome do usuário que você quer se comunicar]`, exemplo `@GuilhermeNascimento` :)