# Envio de e-mail com asp

Tags: email, asp

Boa tarde pessoal,
alguem pode me ajudar a criar um asp para envio de email?
eu vejo vários metodos no google, mas não sei qual posso utilizar e não entendo todos os termos.
Estou tentando colocar em uma página que estou criando no servidor de desenvolvimento aqui do meu estágio.
Alguem pode me dar umas dicas?

Comment: Você esta usando C# ?

Comment: Sua pergunta é muito ampla. Tente detalhar mais, por exemplo, o que você já fez.

Comment: Fiz o site simples em html e css, e queria colocar um formulário de envio de e-mail. O site fica em um servidor gerenciado pelo IIS então acho que tenho que fazer a página de envio em asp certo? ai queria uma ajuda com essa crianção e configuração do asp.

Comment: Você não consegue enviar e-mail só com HTML e CSS. Você precisa fazer o código em C# para fazer isso.

Answer (score 0):

Enviar e-mail não é uma coisa simples. Se for usar `Smtp`, você vai precisar configurá-lo, além disso, o e-mail deve estar configurado corretamente(na aba `Encaminhamento e POP/IMAP`)

Dê uma olhada em: [Enviar e-mail](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/630/como-posso-enviar-um-e-mail-pelo-gmail)